# Can a laptop display directly connect with mobile phone motherboard like iPhone 4s MB. If it's possible then how can one achieve?

Tags: lvds

I have dell vastro 40 pin display and iPhone 4s MB which I want to connect directly to it. Do I have to give separate power supply to the display or will work with phone's supply and can connect with lvds connection available in mobile display connector only with necessary connections.
And what other things I have to keep in mind for working this properly. Need help for this, all the suggestions are welcome

Comment: *I have dell vastro 40 pin display and iPhone 4s MB which I want to connect directly to it.* Explain what you want to achieve by connecting these devices. The power supply will be the least of your problems. Are both LVDS interfaces even compatible? Do you realize how small and inpractical these connections are? Do you have specialized equipment like hot air soldering and a microscope?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible.

While theoretically possible for some cases of phone SoC / screen combinations, it would not only require software modifications that you definitely can't do on an iPhone (Apple makes very sure you can't modify hardware), the engineering effort begged to map pins, design adapter PCBs, design display interface digital logic, supply voltage regulators, adapt the background light control, build something that emulates the old touch screen, and getting all that manufactured would be much more expensive than a new phone and laptop.